# Why is my accuracy or dice score of my SegNet Model not increasing?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am following a some code and a online tutorial to implement SegNet for image segmentation.

I changed the number of out_channels to fit the target size in my model.py:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class SegNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_chn=3, out_chn=1, BN_momentum=0.5):
        super(SegNet, self).__init__()

        #SegNet Architecture
        #Takes input of size in_chn = 3 (RGB images have 3 channels)
        #Outputs size label_chn (N # of classes)

        #ENCODING consists of 5 stages
        #Stage 1, 2 has 2 layers of Convolution + Batch Normalization + Max Pool respectively
        #Stage 3, 4, 5 has 3 layers of Convolution + Batch Normalization + Max Pool respectively

        #General Max Pool 2D for ENCODING layers
        #Pooling indices are stored for Upsampling in DECODING layers

        self.in_chn = in_chn
        self.out_chn = out_chn

        self.MaxEn = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

        self.ConvEn11 = nn.Conv2d(self.in_chn, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn11 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn12 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn12 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvEn21 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn21 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn22 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn22 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvEn31 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn31 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn32 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn32 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn33 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn33 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvEn41 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn41 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn42 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn42 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn43 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn43 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvEn51 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn51 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn52 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn52 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvEn53 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNEn53 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)


        #DECODING consists of 5 stages
        #Each stage corresponds to their respective counterparts in ENCODING

        #General Max Pool 2D/Upsampling for DECODING layers
        self.MaxDe = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=2)

        self.ConvDe53 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe53 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe52 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe52 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe51 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe51 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvDe43 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe43 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe42 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe42 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe41 = nn.Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe41 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvDe33 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe33 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe32 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe32 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe31 = nn.Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe31 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvDe22 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe22 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe21 = nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe21 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=BN_momentum)

        self.ConvDe12 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe12 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=BN_momentum)
        self.ConvDe11 = nn.Conv2d(64, self.out_chn, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.BNDe11 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.out_chn, momentum=BN_momentum)

    def forward(self, x):

        #ENCODE LAYERS
        #Stage 1
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn11(self.ConvEn11(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn12(self.ConvEn12(x)))
        x, ind1 = self.MaxEn(x)
        size1 = x.size()

        #Stage 2
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn21(self.ConvEn21(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn22(self.ConvEn22(x)))
        x, ind2 = self.MaxEn(x)
        size2 = x.size()

        #Stage 3
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn31(self.ConvEn31(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn32(self.ConvEn32(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn33(self.ConvEn33(x)))
        x, ind3 = self.MaxEn(x)
        size3 = x.size()

        #Stage 4
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn41(self.ConvEn41(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn42(self.ConvEn42(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn43(self.ConvEn43(x)))
        x, ind4 = self.MaxEn(x)
        size4 = x.size()

        #Stage 5
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn51(self.ConvEn51(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn52(self.ConvEn52(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNEn53(self.ConvEn53(x)))
        x, ind5 = self.MaxEn(x)
        size5 = x.size()

        #DECODE LAYERS
        #Stage 5
        x = self.MaxDe(x, ind5, output_size=size4)
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe53(self.ConvDe53(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe52(self.ConvDe52(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe51(self.ConvDe51(x)))

        #Stage 4
        x = self.MaxDe(x, ind4, output_size=size3)
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe43(self.ConvDe43(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe42(self.ConvDe42(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe41(self.ConvDe41(x)))

        #Stage 3
        x = self.MaxDe(x, ind3, output_size=size2)
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe33(self.ConvDe33(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe32(self.ConvDe32(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe31(self.ConvDe31(x)))

        #Stage 2
        x = self.MaxDe(x, ind2, output_size=size1)
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe22(self.ConvDe22(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe21(self.ConvDe21(x)))

        #Stage 1
        x = self.MaxDe(x, ind1)
        x = F.relu(self.BNDe12(self.ConvDe12(x)))
        x = self.ConvDe11(x)

        x = F.softmax(x, dim=1)

        return x
```

This is my train.py :

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

import albumentations as A
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchsummary import summary

import pickle
import time

from model import SegNet
from utils import (
    load_checkpoint,
    save_checkpoint,
    get_loaders,
    check_accuracy,
    save_predictions_as_imgs,
)

# Hyperparameters etc.
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
BATCH_SIZE = 15
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
NUM_WORKERS = 2
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300
IMAGE_WIDTH = 300
PIN_MEMORY = True
LOAD_MODEL = False
TRAIN_IMG_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/train_images/"
TRAIN_MASK_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/train_masks/"
VAL_IMG_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/val_images/"
VAL_MASK_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/val_masks/"

def count_parameters(model):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

def train_fn(loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler):
    loop = tqdm(loader)

    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(loop):
        data = data.to(device=DEVICE)
        targets = targets.float().unsqueeze(1).to(device=DEVICE)


        # forward
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            predictions = model(data)
            loss = loss_fn(predictions, targets)

        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        scaler.step(optimizer)
        scaler.update()

        # update tqdm loop
        loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())


def main():
    train_transform = A.Compose(
        [
            A.Resize(height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, width=IMAGE_WIDTH),
            A.Rotate(limit=35, p=1.0),
            A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
            A.VerticalFlip(p=0.1),
            A.Normalize(
                mean=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                std=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                max_pixel_value=255.0,
            ),
            ToTensorV2(),
        ],
    )

    val_transforms = A.Compose(
        [
            A.Resize(height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, width=IMAGE_WIDTH),
            A.Normalize(
                mean=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                std=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                max_pixel_value=255.0,
            ),
            ToTensorV2(),
        ],
    )

    model = SegNet().to(DEVICE)
    loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

    train_loader, val_loader = get_loaders(
        TRAIN_IMG_DIR,
        TRAIN_MASK_DIR,
        VAL_IMG_DIR,
        VAL_MASK_DIR,
        BATCH_SIZE,
        train_transform,
        val_transforms,
        NUM_WORKERS,
        PIN_MEMORY,
    )

    if LOAD_MODEL:
        load_checkpoint(torch.load("my_checkpoint.pth.tar"), model)


    check_accuracy(val_loader, model, device=DEVICE)
    scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()

    acc_record = []

    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        print("Epoch {}".format(epoch+1))
        # print(count_parameters(model))
        starttime = time.time()
        train_fn(train_loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler)
        endtime = time.time()
        runtime = endtime - starttime

        # save model
        checkpoint = {
            "state_dict": model.state_dict(),
            "optimizer":optimizer.state_dict(),
        }
        save_checkpoint(checkpoint)

        acc, dice, traintime = check_accuracy(val_loader, model, device=DEVICE)
        # check accuracy
        acc_record.append([epoch, acc, dice, runtime/BATCH_SIZE, traintime])

        # print some examples to a folder
        save_predictions_as_imgs(
            val_loader, model, folder="saved_images/", device=DEVICE
        )
        if (acc>0.999) and (dice>0.999):
            break

    pickle.dump(acc_record, open("acc_record.p","wb"))

    summary(model, input_size=(IMAGE_CHANNELS, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

import albumentations as A
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchsummary import summary

import pickle
import time

from model import SegNet
from utils import (
    load_checkpoint,
    save_checkpoint,
    get_loaders,
    check_accuracy,
    save_predictions_as_imgs,
)

# Hyperparameters etc.
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
BATCH_SIZE = 15
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
NUM_WORKERS = 2
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300
IMAGE_WIDTH = 300
PIN_MEMORY = True
LOAD_MODEL = False
TRAIN_IMG_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/train_images/"
TRAIN_MASK_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/train_masks/"
VAL_IMG_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/val_images/"
VAL_MASK_DIR = "CT_DATA_AUG/val_masks/"

def count_parameters(model):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

def train_fn(loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler):
    loop = tqdm(loader)

    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(loop):
        data = data.to(device=DEVICE)
        targets = targets.float().unsqueeze(1).to(device=DEVICE)


        # forward
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            predictions = model(data)
            loss = loss_fn(predictions, targets)

        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        scaler.step(optimizer)
        scaler.update()

        # update tqdm loop
        loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())


def main():
    train_transform = A.Compose(
        [
            A.Resize(height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, width=IMAGE_WIDTH),
            A.Rotate(limit=35, p=1.0),
            A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
            A.VerticalFlip(p=0.1),
            A.Normalize(
                mean=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                std=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                max_pixel_value=255.0,
            ),
            ToTensorV2(),
        ],
    )

    val_transforms = A.Compose(
        [
            A.Resize(height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, width=IMAGE_WIDTH),
            A.Normalize(
                mean=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                std=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                max_pixel_value=255.0,
            ),
            ToTensorV2(),
        ],
    )

    model = SegNet().to(DEVICE)
    loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

    train_loader, val_loader = get_loaders(
        TRAIN_IMG_DIR,
        TRAIN_MASK_DIR,
        VAL_IMG_DIR,
        VAL_MASK_DIR,
        BATCH_SIZE,
        train_transform,
        val_transforms,
        NUM_WORKERS,
        PIN_MEMORY,
    )

    if LOAD_MODEL:
        load_checkpoint(torch.load("my_checkpoint.pth.tar"), model)


    check_accuracy(val_loader, model, device=DEVICE)
    scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()

    acc_record = []

    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        print("Epoch {}".format(epoch+1))
        # print(count_parameters(model))
        starttime = time.time()
        train_fn(train_loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler)
        endtime = time.time()
        runtime = endtime - starttime

        # save model
        checkpoint = {
            "state_dict": model.state_dict(),
            "optimizer":optimizer.state_dict(),
        }
        save_checkpoint(checkpoint)

        acc, dice, traintime = check_accuracy(val_loader, model, device=DEVICE)
        # check accuracy
        acc_record.append([epoch, acc, dice, runtime/BATCH_SIZE, traintime])

        # print some examples to a folder
        save_predictions_as_imgs(
            val_loader, model, folder="saved_images/", device=DEVICE
        )
        if (acc>0.999) and (dice>0.999):
            break

    pickle.dump(acc_record, open("acc_record.p","wb"))

    summary(model, input_size=(IMAGE_CHANNELS, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am struggling to understanding why the accuracy is not increasing each epoch. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you very much.

I changed the number of out_channels to fit the target size as initially it was 32, however that threw a error as it didn't match the target size. I think it has something to do with the images being grayscale so it wont be able to accurately segment?

I am very new to CNN's and am trying to learn, sorry if i made any mistakes.

Comment: After outputting the "segmented images", it comes out as just white square as well. I have no clue what is going wrong.

Comment: try to make a _minimal_ example that reproduces your error. Thre are many moving parts in your code. Augmentation, transformations, caching, checkpointing, device transfer. Help others helping you by removing all that seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @LudvigH, i managed to fix the problem. However, in the future will try to be more helpful when asking questions.

Comment: happy you fixed it. good luck with the project!